# problems setting up django-toolbar: the bar is not shown

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up django-toolbar in my production site, so just certain IPs can use it. I have followed the [official documentation](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html) (install and quick setup), but I can't see the toolbar.

The app is installed:

```
$ yolk -l | grep toolbar
django-debug-toolbar - 0.11.0       - active
```

I have added the required settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    'modeltranslation',

    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',

    'debug_toolbar',
    # more stuff...
)

INTERNAL_IPS = ('---.---.---.---',) # my current ip, taken from the server logs so I'm sure it's correct

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEBUG = True
```

There's no error message. I have also run collectstatic just in case. No success.

Any suggestion? Thanks :-)

EDIT: it seems that the order within INSTALLED_APPS matters. Moving 'debug_toolbar' right after all 'django.contrib.*' and before 'modeltranslation' and the others solved the issue.

Comment: What does the browser inspector output? do you see the toolbar js scripts and everything? if yes then you need to check your HTML code (make sure your tags are properly closed).

Comment: Do you have DEBUG=True ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Using the inspector, I can't find any django-toolbar related js file... neither on the site itself nor the admin pages.

Comment: Yes, I have set DEBUG=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason. Within INSTALLED_APPS, 'debug_toolbar' must appear as soon as possible. I had placed some other applications before ('modeltranslation', 'cms', etc.). Placing it just after all 'django.contrib.*' and before the others works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `INTERNAL_IPS` to what is in `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` (second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517765/django-debug-toolbar-not-showing-up))?

I had a similar problem, the toolbar wasn't displaying and I couldn't figure out why. But when I printed `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` my IP wasn't what I thought it was! (because I was using port forwarding and virtual box).

Comment: I have put into INTERNAL_IPS the ip address shown at /var/log/httpd/access_log when I access my server, so I suppose it's the public one. You're right, I thought that my IP was another. But anyhow it doesn't work even after restarting apache.