# unable to run server when django debug toolbar is enabled

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

We are handling a very large django codebase, we are using django debug toolbar, the problem is so weird, if I put `DEBUG_TOOLBAR=True` in my `django.settings` , I am not able to perform any activity with `manage.py` like `python manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py collectstatic` any of it. When I press `CTRL+C` to terminate, I am unable to, it got stuck there. Here is my django debug toolbar configuration.

```
DEBUG=True
DEBUG_TOOLBAR = True
if DEBUG and DEBUG_TOOLBAR:
    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )
    INTERNAL_IPS = (
        '127.0.0.1',
        'XX.XX.XXX.XXX',
    )
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
            'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
            'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
            'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
            'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
            'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
            ]
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'RENDER_PANELS': True,
        'RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE': 2,
        'RESULTS_STORE_SIZE': 10, # Required for ddt_request_history
        'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': lambda request: True
            }

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'saul.middleware.profile.ProfileMiddleware',
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )
```

However, I have gone through the answers of below question, but none of it worked.

[django-debug-toolbar not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517765/django-debug-toolbar-not-showing-up)

Comment: What do you mean "unable to"?  Is there an error message?  What is it?

Comment: @AdamBarnes there is no error message on it....

Comment: So when typing `python manage.py shell` and pressing Enter, you just get a cursor and nothing else?  No error, no prompt?  What happens if you just type `python` and press Enter?

Comment: @AdamBarnes even shell is not working... it doesn't print any error, nothing...  if I type `python` it enters `python` console

Comment: My guess is that you have an infinite loop somewhere in your settings, which would cause python to just spin and never print anything when you use a management command.  Are you able to post more of your code?  If the project isn't sensitive, could you put it on github for us to have a look?

Comment: @AdamBarnes OOPS!!! sorry barnes... the project is private... it is our entire codebase.... really thanks for helping, I will look into this...

Comment: Ok, try running `manage.py shell` while watching `top`, and seeing if `python` jumps to the top of the CPU utilisation list.  That would indicate a loop.

Comment: @AdamBarnes Hi, Yes python has topped up and my aws instance checks failed due to high CPU utilization, have to figure out why...

Comment: Search your settings files for a `while` or `for`.  Make sure that it terminates.

Comment: @AdamBarnes If there's a infinte loop in settings, it's working if I made `DEBUG_TOOLBAR=False` without any changes to settings.

Comment: That's perplexing then; nothing in that block suggests anything like this could happen.  I'd personally now go and comment out a line at a time, and try the shell after each, to see what's causing it.  I'd even go as far as to comment out single values in the config lists, so, for instance, only comment out `'saul.middleware.profile.ProfileMiddleware'`...

Comment: Sure... let me try... Thanks you very much for your help!!! @AdamBarnes

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the answer that we have an infinite loop of `DEBUG_TOOLBAR` set in our multiple settings file, so it's causing a loop there.