# I cannot get django debug toolbar to appear in the browser. Project is attached

Tags: python, django

Its a very simple small project located here https://github.com/cbaldwin20/project_8/tree/master/project_eight

I tried for like two hours to get the 'django debug toolbar' to appear in the browser with no success. I'm not sure if its my code or my computer. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace urls.py from

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
```

to

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('minerals.urls', namespace="minerals")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
    SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = True
```

commented `INTERNAL_IPS  = ["127.0.0.1"]` This is important

remove `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]`

Comment: I don't understand, you first said I need to add the second block of code, but then told me to remove `url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))` which you told me above to add....

Comment: It is already added at your line no. 29, you remove that and keep mine of if condition

Comment: it says 'name 'urlpatterns' is not defined'. On the `+ urlpatterns` it shows an error

Comment: Please check my edits, keep your up and if condition after that

Comment: I tried putting `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[*]`, I had to leave out the `INTERNAL_IPS` because it was giving a FilenotfoundError. It is still not showing up...

Comment: You should uncomment `INTERNAL_IPS`. If you're getting an error then you should include the full traceback of that in your question. If you don't set `INTERNAL_IPS`, then you need to [override the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518040/113962), which makes the configuration more complicated, and could make the debug toolbar output available to other users which is insecure.

Comment: `INTERNAL_IPS` important to have, yes agree with @Alasdair

Comment: Okay. It gives this error when I put in the INTERNAL_IPS. `Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value: 
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\cbaldwin\\Documents\\Python\\project_8\\project_eight\\project_8\\static'`

Comment: No no, wait, actually toolbar worked for your project to me, but I'm using ubuntu, no windows. So I'm not sure, about this issue. But you fire that command and try chaning the setting for BASE_DIR. May be that should solve the issue

Comment: @Anup Yadav    thank you for checking. So its possibly my windows laptop? I am using 'windows command prompt' if that would have anything to do with it?

Comment: May be try here adding this `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'` after line of `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: I put it below and it returned `ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.`

Comment: You don't have a `static` directory in your project directory (the one containing `manage.py`), so you shouldn't have `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),` in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting. You shouldn't have to set `STATIC_ROOT` at this stage - it's only needed when you want to collect your static files to serve them in production.

Comment: So I should replace the `BASE_DIR` with my 'minerals' folder? Like `os.path.join(minerals, 'static')`?

Comment: No, either fire collectstatic command, or remove `STATICFILES_DIRS` or `STATIC_ROOT` settings.

Comment: I removed the STATIC_ROOT but kept the STATICFILES_DIRS and it still gives FileNotFoundError

Comment: remove `STATICFILES_DIRS` as well

Comment: @Anup Yadav   brilliant, that worked. Its now showing up. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer. What happened @Chris couldn't I help you?

Comment: Great! @Chris Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Stackoverflow much I don't know the rules, but you were the first to give the correct solution that I saw. You helped a lot thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Chris It's ok. No issues. I'm happy that I could help you.

Answer (score 2):

<s>add this in `settings.py`</s>

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'settings.show_toolbar'
}
INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar']
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'] + MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```

**Update**
I think I was little rush to the answer, sorry for that.

**Changes** :
**1:** removed this from `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

**2:** added `INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']` to `settings`
**3:** changed `project_8/urls.py` as below,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('minerals.urls', namespace="minerals")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
                      url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
                  ] + urlpatterns
```

Comment: It said ' name 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' is not defined' so I changed 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' to just 'MIDDLEWARE', and then it gave the error ' No module named 'debug_toolbar'.

Comment: I upgraded Django (I didn't realize I was using an old version) and it stopped saying that, but I tried your code again and it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'`

Comment: @Chris Updated the answer

Comment: That worked great. Its now showing thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry I suppose I can only give one accepted answer. I read the other correct answer first, but your answer was also spot on. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing in docker containers, so my case might be a little bit different than yours, but that's the only solution which worked for me.

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns.insert(0, path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)))
```

settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE.append('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')

if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('debug_toolbar')
```

**And that's the most important part from settings.py which made it to finally appear.**

```
if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = type(str('c'), (), {'__contains__': lambda *a: True})()
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
         "code goes here"
        *{
             display: block !important;
         }
    </style>
</head>
```

Just use the style below.

```css
* {
     display: block !important;
 }
```

In the last part of  of that page, you are rendering

https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/commit/c35a2ece8a734a7f42138f84203e3f6cce72c6bd

```css
.djdt-hidden {
                 display: block !important;
             }
```