# Django can' t load Module 'debug_toolbar': No module named 'debug_toolbar'

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

When I try running the project, Django can not load the django-debug-toolbar plugin for some reason. Error message says:

```
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'
```

Here is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ...
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    # ...
]

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1',)
```

Comment: Did you install `django-debug-toolbar` package? Please post your virtual environment requirements.

Comment: Django>=2.0,<3.0
psycopg2>=2.7,<3.0

Comment: I need more information. When does error be raised? `runserver` on your localhost? Or deployment? Are you using docker? If you are, please post your docker settings.

Comment: The Error raise as soon as i add debug_toolbar on my installed_apps. yes im using docker on my localhost. This is what is in my docker-compose.yml: version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

Comment: Show your urls.py, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to re-install `django-debug-toolbar` by adding it to `requirements.txt` and then running:

```bash
docker-compose build web
```

After doing that, the toolbar wasn't still showing. I had to add this code to the settings.py file

```py
def show_toolbar(request):
    return True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
  "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK" : show_toolbar,
}
```

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518040/11011598

Answer (score 27):

If you have not installed the `django-debug-toolbar` package you can install it with help of the below command:

```bash
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

Comment: i did that before adding it to installed_apps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command which worked perfectly for me:

```bash
$ python -m pip install -e git+https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar.git#egg=django-debug-toolbar
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I did run across the same problem when trying to use debug toolbar with Django & docker.

The solution posted above did not solve the problem entirely. The toolbar was sometimes not visible on the `rest_framework` browsable API.

I solved the problem by adding the below into my settings.py

```py
INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1',"0.0.0.0:8000"] 

import socket
hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
INTERNAL_IPS += [".".join(ip.split(".")[:-1] + ["1"]) for ip in ips]
```

ref:
https://knasmueller.net/fix-djangos-debug-toolbar-not-showing-inside-docker

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue because we're using docker containers for the development environment and we're also using Pipenv to manage deps. Silly me, I did:

```
pipenv install django-debug-toolbar --dev
```

When in my environment this does no good because it will never be installed on my docker container environment. I had to reinstall without the `--dev` part and it worked fine afterwards.

Hope this helps someone out in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the import error by moving the debug toolbar middleware to **after** all of the default Django middlewares:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware' # <-- HERE
]
```

With that change, the toolbar didn't display. That's because:

> It will also only display if the MIME type of the response is either text/html or application/xhtml+xml and contains a closing  tag.

My page didn't have a `</body>` closing tag, since the Django tutorial introduced the debug toolbar before introducing page layouts.

I added `<body>` / `</body>` to my page, and the toolbar then displayed.