# I have successfully installed django debug toolbar in my django project. Display error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbarstore)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv

I have successfully installed django debug toolbar in my django project. initially server in run but currently it display this error
I just run my server on cmd and its shows this error.

```
(storefront) C:\Users\Tayyab\Desktop\storefront>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\.virtualenvs\storefront-K3Kf9O1H\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 223, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Tayyab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
****ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbarstore'****
```

Comment: Please show the code for your `INSTALLED_APPS` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54513675/7976758).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did:

1. pip install django-debug-toolbar (pipenv install didn't work for me,
   so only pip)
2. Then python -m pip install Pillow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

recreat path
on window

1. go to `environment variables`
2. select `edit path`
3. create a new path

hopefully it's fixed
nor
reinstall python in your os (make sure before reinstall uninstall first)